# Spring JPA to query same table across different schemas

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa

I'm using Spring JPA against an Oracle database and I want to be able to query the same table across 2 different schemas/databases (e.g., db1.car and db2.car).

My domain object would be pretty standard, as shown below. Is there some way to pass a schema/db qualifier to the domain object via the controller, if say I have a db1.car table and a and db2.car table?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, is there a way to pass the qualified table name into a named query? Doesn't seem to be, as this does not seem to work (i.e., ":qualifiedcar" causes a Spring autowiring error):

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, String> {
    @Query("select p from :qualifiedcar p where p.type in (:type)")
    List<Person> findByQualifiedPersonAndType(@Param("qualifiedcar") String qualifiedcar, @Param("type") String type);
}
```

To clarify, perhaps Oracle doesn't use the term *schema*. It may be more accurate to call them different databases.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the schema in an entity you would have to do it as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car", schema = "db1")
public class CarS1 {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "car", schema = "db2")
public class CarS2 {
    ...
}
```

Regarding the second question, I would try to use programmatic named queries as follows:

```
String dinamicQuery = "Select * from ";
String resultMapping = "";

if (schema.equals("db1")){
    dinamicQuery = dinamicQuery + "table1 ";
    resultMapping = "test1"
}else{
    dinamicQuery = dinamicQuery + "table2 ";
    resultMapping = "test2"
}

Query q = em.createNativeQuery(dinamicQuery,resultMapping);
em.getEntityManagerFactory().addNamedQuery("selectDinamic", q);

return em.createNamedQuery("selectDinamic",Piloto.class).getResultList();
```

The resultMapping is defined in the entities and is necessary to get the objects formatted in the query

```
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name="test1",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = Cars1.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
                [...]
        })
    })
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "car", schema = "db1")
public class CarS1 {
    [...]
}
```